# Python: How to create an ABC that inherits from others ABC?

Tags: python, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance

I am trying to create a simple abstract base class `Abstract` that along with its own methods provides the methods of two others abstract base classes: `Publisher` and `Subscriber`. When I try to initialize the concrete class `Concrete`, built on `Abstract` I get this error: ***Cannot create a consistent method resolution order (MRO) for bases ABC, Publisher, Subscriber***. What is the right way to do it?

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Publisher(ABC):
    
    subscribers = set() 
    
    def register(self, obj):
        self.subscribers.add(obj)
    
    def unregister(self, obj):
        self.subscribers.remove(obj)
    
    def dispatch(self, event):
        print("dispatching", event)
        

class Subscriber(ABC):
    
    @abstractmethod
    def handle_event(self, event):
        raise NotImplementedError
        

class Abstract(ABC, Publisher, Subscriber):
    
    @abstractmethod
    def do_something(self, event):
        raise NotImplementedError
        

class Concrete(Abstract):

    def handle_event(self, event):
        print("handle_event")
    
    def do_something(self, event):
        print("do_something")
    
    

c = Concrete()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Abstract classes don't have to have `abc.ABC` in their list of bases. They have to have `abc.ABCMeta` (or a descendant) as their metaclass, and they have to have at least one abstract method (or something else that counts, like an abstract property), or they'll be considered concrete. (`Publisher` has no abstract methods, so it's actually concrete.)

Inheriting from `ABC` is just a way to get `ABCMeta` as your class's metaclass, for people more comfortable with inheritance than metaclasses, but it's not the only way. You can also inherit from another class with `ABCMeta` as its metaclass, or specify `metaclass=ABCMeta` explicitly.

---

In your case, inheriting from `Publisher` and `Subscriber` will already set `Abstract`'s metaclass to `ABCMeta`, so inheriting from `ABC` is redundant. Remove `ABC` from `Abstract`'s base class list, and everything should work.

Alternatively, if you *really* want `ABC` in there for some reason, you can move it to the end of the base class list, which will resolve the MRO conflict - putting it first says you want `ABC` methods to override methods from the other classes, which conflicts with the fact that the other classes are subclasses of `ABC`.

Comment: PyCharm complain if I have `A(metaclass=ABCMeta)` and `B(A)`, where `B` is abstract (doesn't implement all abstract methods of `A`). Is that just pycharm being silly, or should I explicitly mark B with metaclass=ABCMeta as well?

Comment: @olejorgenb: I would consider that PyCharm being silly. Others might consider it a useful warning. Python itself doesn't require you to put `metaclass=ABCMeta` on `B`.

Answer (score 3):

Change from this:

```py
class Abstract(ABC, Publisher, Subscriber):
```

To this:

```py
class Abstract(Publisher, Subscriber):
```

The two subclasses are already abstract, thus you don't need to inherit from `ABC` again.

Answer (score 0):

class Abstract(Publisher, Subscriber, ABC):

this would be the solution if you want to make sure the class is not instantiable

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).